# Two columns unique strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to find the unique combination of both `person1` and `person2` columns despite the reverse values in my dataframe. Below you can find the initial Dataframe example, where I want to find the unique persons:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"person1":["AL","IN","AN","DL","IN","AL","AL","IN","AN"],
                   "person2":["AL","AN", np.nan,"AL","AN","AL","DL","IN","IN"]})

  person1  person2
0     AL      AL
1     IN      AN
2     AN      NAN
3     DL      AL
4     IN      AN
5     AL      AL
6     AL      DL
7     IN      IN
8     AN      IN
```

My desired output looks like this:

```
  person1  person2  person
0     AL      AL     AL
1     IN      AN    IN/AN
2     AN      NAN    AN
3     DL      AL    DL/AL
4     IN      AN    IN/AN
5     AL      AL     AL
6     AL      DL    DL/AL  # Since it has been added as DL/AL NOT AL/DL
7     IN      IN     IN
8     AN      IN    IN/AN  # Since it has been added as IN/AN NOT AN/IN
```

I used this code:

```
df['person'] = np.where(df.person1 != df.person2,
                                     df.person1 + "/" + df.person2, df.person1)
```

But it returns with `AL/DL` and `AN/IN` in index 6 and 8 in my example above. As always, when I don't see a proper approach, where I can get the unique order of `DL/AL` and `IN/AN`

Pandas gurus, please show me the way :)

Comment: What if there are more than two occurrences of the same two people? What should the column be then? Secondly, do you really need this to be a Pandas dataframe column? Generating the combinations otherwise is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible sorting both columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['person1','person2']].fillna('')), 
                   index=df.index,
                   columns=['person1','person2'])
df['person'] = np.where(df1.person1 != df1.person2,
                        df1.person1.str.cat(df1.person2,  sep="/").str.strip('/'),
                        df1.person1)
print (df)
  person1 person2 person
0      AL      AL     AL
1      IN      AN  AN/IN
2      AN     NaN     AN
3      DL      AL  AL/DL
4      IN      AN  AN/IN
5      AL      AL     AL
6      AL      DL  AL/DL
7      IN      IN     IN
8      AN      IN  AN/IN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `apply()`:

```
df['person']=df.apply(lambda r: r.drop_duplicates().sort_values().str.cat(sep='/'), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  person1 person2 person
0      AL      AL     AL
1      IN      AN  AN/IN
2      AN     NaN     AN
3      DL      AL  AL/DL
4      IN      AN  AN/IN
5      AL      AL     AL
6      AL      DL  AL/DL
7      IN      IN     IN
8      AN      IN  AN/IN
```